# Accidentally uploaded app with unsigned key alias onto the Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I accidentally uploaded my app to the Play Store with the Key Alias signing being set to debug. Should I remove it from the Play Store and upload it under a different Bundle ID or is it ok to keep it as is?

Comment: Remove it. You very likely don't keep special copy of your debug key (so reinstalling computer or using other computer will produce different debug key), and it's expiration date may be too near. Losing the signing key would force you to abandon the app in store (no more updates possible).

Answer (score 1):

If you had a previous apk uploaded to the PlayStore, I think you can rollback to the older version, recompile your new apk and upload the updated version. If this is your first time uploading an apk to this listing, then just remove the apk and upload the correct one.

Comment: Had he published the application signed with proper key already, it wouldn't accept update signed by debug key.